# REGEX working together separated by | OR. When run independently are both returning empty lists

Tags: python, arrays, regex, string, parsing

I have written two REGEX that I originally was using with the | either or. I need them to both run separately, what should be a simple matter of doing is not working the way I expected. I have tested both regex with online tools, and they both work 100%. When ran in the code they both return: [].

For reference stringSoup is an html string.

Here was the original:

```
re.findall(r"(\(@([^)\s]+)\))|//.*instagram\.com/(\w+.*?)/(?:p)/g")
```

I need to run each re separately like so:

```
re.findall(r"(\(@([^)\s]+)\))/g", stringSoup) 

re.findall(r"//.*instagram\.com/(\w+.*?)/(?:p)/g", stringSoup)
```

The first regex is to find usernames as (@username) The second is to find usernames as instagram.com/username

The original combined regex was working fine

After separation both of these are returning empty []

Comment: Can you share your code? Please see: [mcve].

Comment: Is the `/g` at the end meant as a flag? If so, Python doesn't support this notation.

Comment: @MichaelButscher yes it is meant to be global, could you please share the resolution to that

Comment: Just take out the `/g`. You're already searching the whole string, and all the `g` flag does is to say "search the whole string instead of just at the start".

Comment: @mypetlion lol you're 100% right, while I was testing online had the /g flag

Comment: Looks like it's working now after removing the /g flag. I will update if there's still an issue! Thank you :)

Comment: @mypetlion out of curiosity why did the first regex work with the /g flag but the other two didn't ?

Comment: Most likely because it matched the first part of OR.

You can add flags to a regex using `flags` arguments
for example, `re.findall(r"(\(@([^)\s]+)\))|//.*instagram\.com/(\w+.*?)/(?:p)", flafs=re.I)`

You can find more such flags here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really certain I understand your question and some of the inputs, but I made a sample to hopefully re-create what you're trying to do:

```
\(@(?P<username1>[^)]+)\)                  # username is after '(@' and is everything up until ')'
|                                          # or
.*instagram\.com\/(?P<username2>[^\/]+)\/p # username is between 'instagram.com/' and the next '/'
```

You can view it [here](https://regex101.com/r/NlV0MK/3). You can also remove the top half or the bottom half and see that each regex will only match that specific item. Note that using something like `[^\/]` might be a bit crude and you can make that more specific, but the above should give you what you need in a general sense.